# reference to void

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, function-pointers

I have a sneaky feeling this may be an issue due to compilers.

`void SetRenderFunction(void (&newRenderFunction(void)));`

This is causing GCC to proclaim that I "cannot declare reference to ‘void’"

Now, I have used the same function prototype (more or less) under Visual Studio on Windows. On Windows I had a different function name, and rather than passing in a pointer to a function that takes void, it took a pointer to some other object that I needed.

If I use `*` rather than `&` It prevents this issue, but instead when I try to pass in the function pointer, I get type casting issues:  it's trying to cast it from `void (*)()` to `void* (*)()`

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ How to create a function which takes as argument a reference to a function pointer ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684576/c-how-to-create-a-function-which-takes-as-argument-a-reference-to-a-function-po)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... it's been indirectly answered by the other people. Thanks to Alf and Abyx I noticed what it was that I did wrong, but as they both posted at more or less the same time, and neither of them actaully said what was wrong just said what was the correct way to do what I was trying, I shall to the old self answer.

My function call was:

`void SetRenderFunction(void (&newRenderFunction(void)));`

The bit that was wrong is here - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ^ and - ^

I should have put a set of brackets around `&newRenderFunction` and the parameters for this function pointer. Like so:

`void SetRenderFunction(void (&newRenderFunction)(void));`

The fix is here - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ^  - - - - - ^

Comment: +1 for answering your own question in a way that will surely be helpful to others.

Comment: That's why I did it. I wasn't out to self answer, but felt that the answers so far didn't really explain what was actually wrong with my code, basically, just a silly typo.

Answer (score 3):

Fails to compile with [Comeau Online](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/). Ergo, it’s wrong.

You can do …

```
void setRenderFunction( void (&newRenderFunction)() );
```

… but better do …

```
void setRenderFunction( void (*newRenderFunction)() );
```

… because the pointer notation is more well known and works also with C.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: erm... don't want to sound like a little shit here, but I know it's wrong, I was more after knowing how to fix it

Comment: `+1` for the first paragraph. I remember trying to file compiler bugs with Metrowerks and Microsoft, and those insisting on their compiler not being faulty according to the standard, until I learned to tell them what Comeau would do. ("But como does this different than you do!") They would always accepted Comeau's verdict. `:)` (I have, over a decade, found one bug in Comeau. Just that one. I found dozens in CW, GCC and VC. Dozens in each one, mind you. All hail EDG.)

Answer (score 2):

```
void SetRenderFunction(void (*newRenderFunction)(void));
void SetRenderFunction(void (&newRenderFunction)(void));
```